# Creating a debug target in Linux 2.6 driver module makefile

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to be able to execute "make debug" at the command line and it will build my driver module with the -DDEBUG_OUTPUT define, which will cause certain sections of code to be compiled in.

In 2.4 kernel makefiles, this is pretty easy.  I just create a debug: target and included "-DDEBUG_OUTPUT" in the cc compilation command arguments for that target.  Easy.

Unfortunately (for me), 2.6 completely changed how modules are compiled, and I can ONLY seem to find the trivial "all" and "clean" examples, which don't show adding custom defines at compilation time.

I tried this:

```
  debug:
    make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS='pwd' -DDEBUG_OUTPUT modules
```

and got a complaint from make.

I've also tried:

.PHONY:  debug

```
debug:
  make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS='pwd' EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(EXTRA_CFLAGS) -DDEBUG_OUTPUT" modules
```

but it is not seeing what EXTRA_CFLAGS contains.  I can see from the command line output that it does correctly append the -D onto the existing EXTRA_CFLAGS, which includes the -I for includes dir.  However, the driver file won't compile now because it cannot find the includes dir...so somehow it is not seeing what EXTRA_CFLAGS contains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "-D" option is not meant to be passed to make: it is a C preprocesseor (cpp) option.

To define DEBUG_OUTPUT for your build you have to add the following line to your Kbuild file:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DDEBUG_OUTPUT
```

Afterwards you can call, as usual:

```
make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=`pwd`
```

EDIT: If you don't want to edit the Kbuild file, you can have a debug target like this:

```
INCLUDES="-Imy_include_dir1 -Imy_include_dir2"

.PHONY: debug
debug:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=`pwd` EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(INCLUDES) -DDEBUG_OUTPUT"
```

EDIT#2:

```
MY_CFLAGS=-DFOO -DBAR -Imydir1

all:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=`pwd` EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(MY_CFLAGS)"

debug: MY_CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG_OUTPUT
debug:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=`pwd` EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(MY_CFLAGS)"
```

Comment: Ok, I can do that, but how do I conditionally set EXTRA_CFLAGS to that value, based on if I want "make debug" instead of just "make"?  I tried putting the EXTRA_CFLAGS assignment directly under the debug target, but I got a command not found on EXTRA_CFLAGS.

Comment: I amended the answer with a debug target.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mircea.  I put that string in there, but the driver file won't compile now because it claims to be missing a .h file that is in the include dir specified by -I in the EXTRA_CFLAGS.  In other words, putting that EXTRA_CFLAGS= part of the make command is causing make to not be able to see the -I<includes> part of EXTRA_CFLAGS.  I added it above to my original post.

Comment: I wouldn't use the EXTRA_CFLAGS in such a "recursive" manner. See my latest edit involving the INCLUDES variable.

Comment: That is good advice, and I made that change.  I reverted back to a simple test for my "all" target, and I find that if I set EXTRA_CFLAGS before my target, then it all works.  But if I set EXTRA_CFLAGS to the exact same value but on the make command line, then it doesn't work (can't see the includes).  Should setting EXTRA_CFLAGS on the make line work the exact same as setting it elsewhere in the Makefile.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: See my second edit. Just set your "usual" flags in something like MY_CFLAGS and add the debug ones in the first line of the debug target . Don't try setting EXTRA_CFLAGS in your console when invoking make: it won't get exported.

Comment: I'm sorry...when I was saying command line, I meant the line in the makefile under the debug target.  I didn't mean when actually issuing the "make" command or "make debug".  So in that regard, I was trying that idea of setting all of the flags elsewhere, and then assigning them to EXTRA_CFLAGS on the make command under the "all" target.  And it still didn't see the includes.  I'll try again, verbatim what you have.

Comment: Awesome, it works!  Here's what was messing me up...the includes path was a relative path.  When set in the EXTRA_CFLAGS in the makefile and not in the build target script, it works.  But take that same relative path and set EXTRA_CFLAGS in the build target line and it suddenly doesn't.  Is it the -C doing that (changing directory?)  Anyway, thanks!  I can now build the debug version on whim!