# How to set preprocessor directives in makefile for kernel module build target?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kbuild

I have a kernel module I'd like to build with any of `make`, `make debug`, `make test`, where the only difference between each one is a `-D` option to the compiler.  This is essentially the same question as [Creating a debug target in Linux 2.6 driver module makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7714714/1488762), but that one was marked as answered, and my question remains, after trying a few other things as well.

I've tried the deprecated `EXTRA_CFLAGS` option in my makefile:

```
debug:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DDEBUG" modules
```

as well as the newer `ccflags-y` option (doesn't seem to work even outside of the `debug` target):

```
ccflags-y := -DDEBUG
debug:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

and setting `CFLAGS` just before the `debug` target:

```
debug: CFLAGS_main.o=-DDEBUG
debug:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

but the only way I've found to accomplish what I want is with a separate build script:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    debug)
        make CFLAGS_main.o=-DDEBUG
        ;;  
    *)  
        make
        ;;  
esac
```

Is there no way to do this directly in the makefile when building a kernel module??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use your original version that used `EXTRA_CFLAGS`, but just replace `EXTRA_CFLAGS` with `ccflags-y`:

```
debug:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) ccflags-y="-DDEBUG" modules
```

or replace it with `CFLAGS_main.o` to apply the CFLAGS to a single object:

```
debug:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) CFLAGS_main.o="-DDEBUG" modules
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned by the OP Roger Dueck, setting variables on the `make` command line has a global effect. It overrides any setting of the same variables within the makefiles which may be undesirable, especially for a globally used variable such as `ccflags-y`.  To avoid this, use your own makefile variable.  In the "normal" part of the Makefile that invokes `$(MAKE)` on the "KBuild" part, change the `debug:` target to the following, using a custom variable of your choice (I used `FOO_CFLAGS` here):

```
debug:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) FOO_CFLAGS="-DDEBUG" modules
```

In the "KBuild" part of the Makefile invoked by the above rule, use the following to append the custom CFLAGS from `FOO_CFLAGS` to `ccflags-y`:

```
ccflags-y += $(FOO_CFLAGS)
```

Comment: The first solution with `ccflags-y` is something I had tried, but it doesn't work for me - does it for you? To test, I use `$(MAKE) -n ...` and then run `make debug 2>&1 | grep DEBUG`.

Comment: The second works!  Two things I'm not satisfied with, though: (1) I can't apply this globally to all sources without using `CFLAGS` (which may already have other options), and have to explicitly specify `main.o`, and (2) this clobbers existing options in `CFLAGS_main.o` (I also tried `CFLAGS_main.o+="-DDEBUG"`, but it still overwrites instead of appending).  I'll wait a bit to see if there's a better answer out there before accepting this one.

Comment: I tried `ccflags-y` on several kernels from 3.16 onwards and it worked, but as you point out above, any changes to variables set on the `make` command line will be ignored (unless the makefile uses the `override` command to change it). Please see my edited answer for a method using a custom variable of your choosing to pass the extra CFLAGS.

Comment: Digging into the "KBuild" makefile isn't so simple (the one I have doesn't include `ccflags-y` or `EXTRA_CFLAGS` anywhere), but looks like the only way to make everything work perfectly.  Happily, I can carry on with your first answer, with `CFLAGS_main.o="-DDEBUG"` for now. Thanks!